# Correct use of the Appnexus API

Tags: curl

For a reporting tool we are building we are retrieving data from the AppNexus(Xandr) API.
Currently we are retrieving all Insertion Orders, Line Items and Creatives every night because we could not find a way to retrieve only items with a modified date after our last pull.

I did find that i should be able to filter on the field last_modified however when i enter a date like '2019-08-01' i do not get any results. I was expecting to get all items after the date set.

Is this the intended way or is there a better way to pull less data?

Comment: This has nothing to do with `curl`.

Comment: From [documentation](https://wiki.appnexus.com/display/api/API+Semantics): `Note the required date/time syntax in the preceding example: YYYY-MM-DD+HH:MM:SS`

Comment: This sounds like a question far better suited to AppNexus technical support than Stack Overflow.

Comment: I agree, i could not find a better tag then Curl.
I tried adding: "last_modified=2019-09-05+00:00:00" and i am still getting an empty response.
I will try to contact AppNexus technical support thanks

Answer (score 0):

Today i have learned that it is possible to use greater/smaller than in URL's.
Changing = to >= solved my problem.
https://api.appnexus.com/creative?last_modified>='2019-07-05 00:00:00'